# Why ASP.NET_SessionId cookie:has same property twice SameSite=Lax;SameSite=None?

Tags: .net, cookies, sessionid, samesite

I am working on .net 4.5.2 framework and added below code to assign SameSite = None for ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.

```
<rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="AddSameSiteCookieFlag">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="^(.*)(ASP.NET_SessionId)(=.*)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0};SameSite=None;" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

Response Header:
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX; path=/; HttpOnly; **SameSite=Lax;SameSite=None;**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just appending `SameSite=None` to the `Set-Cookie` header. This is not what you want to do. Something in your code is already setting `SameSite=Lax` on the cookie.

Remove this and test your application. It's unlikely you need `SameSite=None` for your session cookie, unless your site always runs inside a cross-site context (such as an iframe on a separate site)

If you really do need `SameSite=None` then either:

- Find the place in the code where this is being set to `Lax` and change it to `None`
- Find the place this is being set in the code and remove it, then just use the rule above to append `SameSite=None`.

**Note**: If you do need `SameSite=None` you **must** also set `Secure`.

See: https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/ for more detail.